# How can I get favorite-post according to User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Now,I am developing favorite function for my rails project.
My code is below.

model

**User.rb**

```
has_many :favorites
```

**Favorite.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

**Post.rb**

```
has_many :favorites
```

**my controller**

```
@favorite = current_user.favorite.posts
```

I can not get favorite posts data of current-user this way.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You have to make a `many-to-many` relationship with `has_many :through`.

Try something like this:

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :posts, through: :favorites # OR
  has_many :favorite_posts, class_name: 'Post', through: :favorites  # <= If you want to make it more clear you can add it also in this way
end
```

**Favorite Model**

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**Post**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :users, through: :favorites
end
```

After adding this associations, you can make calls like `User.first.posts` or `User.first.favorite_posts` and you will get all the users favorite posts back.

You will find more information in the [Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Comment: Might be more descriptive to use a different name for the favourite posts association: `has_many :favorite_posts, class_name: 'Post', through: :favorites` which lets you access it with `User.first.favorite_posts`

Comment: Yes I thought about the same, but for simplicity I added it just in this way. But you are right I will add it as comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `user` and `favorites` has many-to-one relation.

You need to find favorites for user like this way

```
current_user.favorites #notice the plural of favorite
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To add to `Tobias`'s answer, this looks like the standard [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association. This would give direct access to the `post` objects, allowing you to call them as you need:

[image]

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :favorites
   has_many :posts, through: :favorites
end

#app/models/favorite.rb
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :post
end

#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :favorites
   has_many :users, through: :favorites
end
```

This would allow you to call:

```
@favorite_posts = @user.posts
```

--

A small twist could be done as follows:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :favorites
   scope :favorite_posts, -> { includes(:posts).where(post: {id: favorites.pluck(:post_id)}) }
end
```

This would allow you to call `@posts = current_user.favorite_posts` and have all the post objects returned as required.

Answer (score -3):

The better approach for this kind of system would be to have many-to-many association between `User` and `Post` so that you can have direct access to the posts that a user adds to its favorites list. However, if you still want to go on with your current design the following code might come in handy:

```
current_user.favorites.collect(&:post)
```

This will first get `current_user`'s all `favorite` objects and then return you the relative `post` against each favorite record.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Comment: Thanks @Drenmi, i am going to update my answer with explanation.